# Query Mongo Db and filter by associative array key

Tags: php, mongodb

How can I search for results in Mongo DB documents using an associative array key.
Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE keyword like '%searchterm%';
```

Here is the basic document structure

```
[id] => 31605
[keywords] => Array (
    [keyword1] => Array (
        [name] => KeyWord1,
        [type] => sometype,
        ...
    )
    [keyword2] => Array (
        [name] => KeyWord2,
        [type] => sometype,
        ...
    )
    ...
)
```

I would like to do a search within the keywords array on the associative array key [keyword1, keyword2].

The issue is that the name key holds the case-sensitive version of the keyword and the array key is the lower-case keyword name.  I could store the lowercase keyword twice, but that seems silly.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know if keyword1 exists

> { keywords.keyword1 : { $exists : true } }

Comment: But what I want to do is actually search the indexes.  I can't say keywords.keyword1 because I actually want to search FOR 'keyword1'.  I want to search by index, not by value.

Comment: Is there a way to search for any document where name=KeyWord1?  I could have any number of subArrays inside keywords and I want to search through.

Comment: Mongodb doesn't allow searching descendants. Collections should be structured similarly to allow indexing and querying, even if there is no schema that's enforced.